# PayPal authentication problem on azure "live store"

Tags: paypal, invoice

I am getting the following error when trying to use paypal API

```
HttpStatusCode: Unauthorized; AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE; Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header.
```

But problem is only when i publish my code to Azure Api. Live store works if I run it on visual studio.

```
    public async Task<bool> InvoicingCreate(Models.ShopTransaction t)
    {
        sentJson = null;
        if (_accessToken == null) await GetAccessTokenAsync();

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "v2/invoicing/invoices");
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _accessToken.access_token);

        bool addNotes;
        if (t.Product.TotalPrice == 0.0) addNotes = false;
        else if (t.PaymentMethod == null) addNotes = true;
        else if (t.PaymentMethod == "paypal" || t.PaymentMethod == "credit_card") addNotes = false;
        else addNotes = true;

        string billingEmail;
        if (t.Product.IndividualCouponId.HasValue)
        {
            billingEmail = _configuration["Shop:CouponInvoiceEmail"];
        }
        else
        {
            billingEmail = t.BillingAddress.Email;
        }
        var inv = new Root
        {
            detail = new Detail
            {

        .......details the items. ...
            },


        .......Fill the items. ...


        sentJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inv, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore });

        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inv), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
        {
            Error error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Error>(content);
            throw new Exception(CompactError("Invoicing-create", response.StatusCode, error));
        }
        CreateResponse invoiceCreated = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreateResponse>(content);

        t.InvoiceId = invoiceCreated.href.Split('/').Last();

        return true;
    }
```

[Auth methode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lxmr.jpg)

[appsettings.json paypalmodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9zSo.jpg)

Invoicing methode

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure to read [ask] and [edit] your question to improve its quality: Don't *ever* prefer images of text over the actual text -- please use code blocks containing the text of your two screenshots! (Note that your "invoicing method" is also missing.) Also, in case you have any more debugging information than "it doesn't work in production when it works locally", please include it in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
It's an domain issue. It has send to many request on paypal server. So classic denial of service.